# Android AsyncTask not executing when called second time

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I have a class which extends AsyncTask

```
public class SendJSONArray2Server extends AsyncTask<String, Void, HttpResponse>
```

the class send a JSONArray to the server and receives response as JSONArray. I have instantiated the class as follows

```
private SendJSONArray2Server sendJSON;
String[] params = { "http://10.0.2.2:8084/xyz/abc",jsonArray.toString() };
sendJSON.execute(params);
```

In onPostExecute I process the user response

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse response)
```

AsyncTask is executed first time like charm and I am receiving the response from the Server but when I try to send JSONArray to server for the second time AsyncTask does not execute.

I am not getting any exceptions or errors in logcat.

Comment: Are you trying to use the same `SendJSONArray2Server` instance both times? That is not supported -- you need to create separate instances.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, I am trying to use the same instance both times. Got your point. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a seperate instance of your async task and try to execute like this..

```
 new MyAsyncTask().execute(params);
```

because **The Asynctask can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted)**

Comment: But what happen with the other asynkTask?

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to run an AsyncTask more than once. Create a separate instance for each run.

Answer (score 1):

The AsyncTask can be executed only once. Make sure you are not missing the exception thrown in console. I looked in the source code for the method that actually does the execution and pasted it bellow. As you see, an exception will be thrown when you try to execute it the second time.

```
public final AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> executeOnExecutor(Executor exec,
        Params... params) {
    if (mStatus != Status.PENDING) {
        switch (mStatus) {
            case RUNNING:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot execute task:"
                        + " the task is already running.");
            case FINISHED:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot execute task:"
                        + " the task has already been executed "
                        + "(a task can be executed only once)");
        }
    }

    mStatus = Status.RUNNING;

    onPreExecute();

    mWorker.mParams = params;
    exec.execute(mFuture);

    return this;
}
```

Comment: instead of using an attribute we can use GetStatus() ?